# Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonpac__name_ is not defined in webpack3/angular 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

Hi I am using Webpack 3 and Angular 4 app. below is my base.config for webpack. I am creating a seperate bundle for a js file in my typescript project.

```
'entry': {
  'main': [
    './src/main.ts'
  ],
  'polyfills': [
    './src/polyfills.ts'
  ],
  'styles': [
    './src/styles/styles.scss'
  ],
  'javascriptlib': [
    './src/javascriptlib.js'
  ]
},
```

Also, I am adding that to commonchunks plugin:

```
new CommonsChunkPlugin({
  'name': 'javascriptlib',
  'chunks': ['javascriptlib']
}),
```

In my project folder structure under src I have javascriptlib.js file.

In HTML of my app I am referring that file:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="javascriptlib.bundle.js"></script>
```

After running webpack dev server on app's load time I am getting below error:

```
VM1261 javascriptlib.bundle.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonpac__name_ is not defined
at VM1261 javascriptlib.bundle.js:2
```

What is wrong here? I don't understand what I am missing here.

My intention here is to use javascriptlib.js in my ts project. javascriptlib.js doesn't have typings and it's very big file to convert to ts due to time constraint. I want to use javascriptlib.js as is. if there is any otherway I can achieve please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: can someone help me how can I convert my javascript library file to typescript?

Comment: Your main bundle should be loaded in your Html before your other bundles